# FileSystemWatcher Created event not firing for files that has been moved from zip archive

Tags: c#, events, drag-and-drop, 7zip, filesystemwatcher

I have a very simple scenario where FSW just doesn't work. I use code like that to setup the watcher:

```
private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"folderToListenForChanges"))

private void Listen(){ 
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.NotifyFilter =
                NotifyFilters.FileName |
                NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                NotifyFilters.Security |
                NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                NotifyFilters.Size;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
            watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;
            watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
            watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
            watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }
```

Let say that there is a zip archive containing single file and folder similar to this one:

Some Dir
\ some file.txt

The zip archive is outside "folderToListenForChanges".
The thing is that when I open this archive with 7zip and use drag&drop to copy the "Some Dir" folder of the archive into the "folderToListenForChanges", FSW fire event only for directory creation but NOT for file creation. Any ideas?

Comment: FSW tends to be flaky, there are a lot of situations it doesn't work quite right in.

Comment: A zip archive is a file.   Its contents are made to *look* like files within the NTFS file system but they are not actually that.  I would never expect `FileSystemWatcher` to be able to detect changes within one.

Comment: I'm NOT trying to detect any changes in the zip itself, but changes in "folderToListenForChanges". The zip archive is just a source from where "Some Dir" has been copied into the "folderToListenForChanges". Note that If I open the zip with windows file explorer all events arrived!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you show what `folderToListenForChanges` actually is? --  Remember to setup your FSW between `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` calls. Set the `Path` property between these calls, too. -- Test only `FileName` and `DirectoryName` as filters.

Comment: folderToListenForChanges  is plain directory on my PC, for example: "C:\Users\yosif.chumpov\Desktop\folderToListenForChanges"

Comment: Have you tested a path that doesn't represent a *special* virtual folder?

Comment: I have just make the same test but with different folder path. This time I used "D:\folderToListenForChanges"  instead of  "C:\Users\...\Desktop\folderToListenForChanges" and now all events are fired! How this is possible?

Comment: `Desktop` is special folder. The container folder is listed (it modifies the Directory you're watching), but the file is created *somewhere else* (as far as `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is concerned).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know if I will be able to fix this but it is good to know what is going on the background.